# CMS, Framework, MVC

Tags: framework, php, cms

в чем разница между CMS framework и MVC? по-сути СУС это уже готовый сайт который можно допилить без знания програмирования, а вот фреймворк и MVC посути одно и тоже но почему же говорят что это разные вещи?

Answer (score 3):

Эм, CMS и MVC это вообще разные вещи.

[CMS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E8%F1%F2%E5%EC%E0_%F3%EF%F0%E0%E2%EB%E5%ED%E8%FF_%F1%EE%E4%E5%F0%E6%E8%EC%FB%EC) -  система управления сайтом. Готовая система, к которой нужно только прилепить дизайн.

[MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) - архитектура Model View Controller.

Framework - Это каркас программной системы (или подсистемы). Может включать вспомогательные программы, библиотеки кода, язык сценариев и другое ПО, облегчающее разработку и объединение разных компонентов большого программного проекта. Обычно объединение происходит за счёт использования единого API. (взято [отсюда](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D4%F0%E5%E9%EC%E2%EE%F0%EA))

Answer (score -1):

CMS - Готовый продукт.

MVC - Инструмент.

CMF - CMS + MVC (грубо говоря)